# "At last, a women's magazine to explode the myth that thin equals beautiful." — Is it grammatical to build sentences without a predicator?

Tags: parsing, predicate

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/explode):
**(1)** **At last, a women's magazine to explode the myth that thin equals beautiful**.

It seems to me (1) consists only of the adjunct "*at last*" and the subject (the noun phrase) "*a women's magazine to explode the myth that thin equals beautiful*". But where is a predicator? Is it grammatical to build sentences without a predicator?

update:
This example begins with a capital letter and has a full stop (period) at the end. That means the dictionary considers it as a sentence.

Comment: Not every example in a dictionary is a complete sentence, especially in smaller dictionaries or usage examples in learners' dictionaries.

Comment: There is no matrix predicator. It could just be an NP in a headline or similar compressed construction with an infinitival relative clause. Compare the finite ".. a women's magazine that can explode the myth that thin equals beautiful".

Comment: @StuartF I'm inferring from your comment that you say the dictionary does not consider this example as a sentence. But then why does it begin with a capital letter and have a full stop (period) at the end? Only sentences can have such traits.

Comment: "Only sentences begin with a capital letter and have a full stop at the end" —Well, obviously not. There, I just did it again! If we're in a context that makes it appropriate to use sentence fragments, then we would still style them. And there could actually be many contexts in which this example could be appropriate, not just informal conversational contexts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a "sentence".

It is common for some utterances that are not clauses.  For example

"At last, The 1948 Show" was the title of a comedy (from the 1960s)  Even if an utterance has sentence punctuation, it might not be a sentence. Here you can see clearly that there is no verb.

Your example is the same.  It is a noun phrase headed by "magazine" with various adjuncts "women's" and "to explode...." and a "fronted adverbial", At last.

You could interpret this as "At last,  [This is] a women's magazine..."  So the entire phrase is the predicator.

Comment: Agreed. The same linked page has other such dictionary examples: "to increase suddenly and very quickly in number."

Comment: You wrote this isn't a sentence. But then why does it begin with a capital letter and have a full stop (period) at the end? Only sentences can have such traits.

Comment: "Even if an utterance has sentence punctuation, it might not be a sentence."  A sentence is based on one or more clauses.  This isn't a clause. The author can use full stops and capital letters and it doesn't make it a sentence.

Comment: @Loviii Note: it's not the punctuation that makes something a sentence, it's the way the words in it work. If I de-capitalize the first letter of a sentence and take away its terminal punctuation, it's still a sentence; it would just be missing standard style.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, your example is not a sentence and can't stand alone. It does not have a finite verb (predicator). It could be written as:

At last, here is [finite verb or predicator] a women's magazine to explode the myth that thin equals beautiful.
Or,

At last, a women's magazine exploded the myth that thin equals beautiful.

There might be other ways to introduce a finite verb.

Thanks!

Comment: I would argue strongly that there isn't necessarily anything "wrong" with the example. No, it's not a sentence, but yes, it *can* stand alone and there are many contexts in which it could be used appropriately.